# Understanding DB Design

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, pdo

I wanted to make a database to store examination marks. I was wondering if it is better to have

- a table for each subject which will make a single record for a roll number

or

- have a marks table which will have multiple records for a roll number for every subject

Since the number of subjects is not fixed, which approach would be better.

For the first method, As the tables would be created using php dynamically, so the table names will become a variable, so that will mean extra sanitisation work,

For the second method, the roll number will have many duplicates

Since I am new to DBMS, so any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This will probably get closed as primarily opinion-based, but really, don't make a table for each subject.

Comment: @Don'tPanic So the second method is alright?

Comment: I think you need to get acquainted with data normalization concepts.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Have one table for subjects, the marks table can have a unique constraint on the subject and roll number combo so that for each subject there will only be one mark, per roll number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one good reason to choose the second method over the first. Let's say you want to get all marks for a specific roll number. (Using `1` for example.) With the second method, it's just:

```
SELECT * FROM marks WHERE roll_number = 1;
```

With the first method (unless someone else knows a better way to do it), it's:

```
SELECT * FROM subject_a WHERE roll_number = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM subject_b WHERE roll_number = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM subject_c WHERE roll_number = 1
...
```

and so on, for each one of your unknown number of subject tables.